# Как скачать частный пакет npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, пакетный-менеждер

Надо скачать частный пакет npm c https://registry.npmjs.org/
Не могу понять как мне настроить токен и установить зависимости с этим пакетом
Пакет чужой, но принадлежит фирме с которой работаем
Я в свою очередь зарегистрировался в npm, создал classic токен (не уверен, что он нужен) и авторизовался в npm с устройства через npm login. По прежнему не могу скачать пакет и не пойму сейчас что делать